# better way to call global config variables from another modules

Tags: vba

I have three modules in my VBA project:

module 1: config_variable

module 2: main_script1

module 3: main_script2

In "config_variable", the codes like this:

```
Public dir_source1 As String
Public dir_source2 As String
Public dir_source3 As String

Sub global_config()
    dir_source1 = range("A2").value
    dir_source2 = range("A3").value
    dir_source3 = range("A4").value
End Sub
```

I manage all configurations in this script. And I call this "global_config" Sub for each Sub in module 2 and module 3 to get global variables. Like this:

module 2 - main_script1:

```
Sub my_sub1()
    ' call global variables
    Call config_variable.global_config
    
    ' main codes for my_sub1
    .....    
End Sub

Sub my_sub2()
    ' call global variables
    Call config_variable.global_config
    
    ' main codes for my_sub2
    .....    
End Sub
```

module 3 - main_script2:

```
Sub my_sub3()
    ' call global variables
    Call config_variable.global_config
    
    ' main codes for my_sub3
    .....    
End Sub
```

The problem is that I need to call the line "Call config_variable.global_config"  in the beginning of each Sub.

Is it possible I can just run this line once and every Sub in the same modules can catch the global variables? Like this:

```
' call global variables on top of each modules
Call config_variable.global_config

Sub my_sub1()
    ' main codes for my_sub1
    .....    
End Sub

Sub my_sub2()
    ' main codes for my_sub2
    .....    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the setting of the global variables when you launch your workbook or project file:

```
Call config_variable.global_config
```

Of course, if the range values may change during a session, you will have to reset the global variabels after such a change.

Comment: I tried this and it works:  
"Sub Auto_Open()
    Call config_variable.global_config
End Sub"   

But there is a major problem. If there is a bug and the macro break, the user have to reopen the file in order to execute this line again.
 Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: That will only happen if you haven't implemented proper error handling.

Answer (score 1):

If settings values are stored in sheet cells, there is no need to move them to global variables at all. You can take those values directly from the cells. For convenience, you can name these cells and refer to them, for short, with `[]` (syntactic sugar = `Evaluate()`). If the settings are not called very often, this method may be suitable, requiring no variables to be updated. For example:

```vb
Sub run_once() ' or make names manually
    For Each x In Array("dir_source1:A2", "dir_source2:A3", "dir_source3:A4")
        y = Split(x, ":")
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add y(0), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range(y(1))
    Next
End Sub

Sub UsageExample()
    Debug.Print "dir_source1 = " & [dir_source1]    ' equivalent for ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If "config_variable" is a standard module (as it looks to be), you can simple call the sub as `global_config`. It is not `Private` and it will be called. But, I should suggest you to call it only if one of the `Public` variable is "" (nullString):

```
If dir_source1 = "" Then global_config
```

In this way, even if an error occurred and the `Public` variable lost their value, they will be used only after `global_config` runs and give values to them.

Comment: Thank you! I think I would consider integrating your suggestion with the solution from the first answer.

Comment: @codingsnake99 What to integrate? The solution is in the answer... You should simple replace `Call config_variable.global_config` with `If dir_source1 = "" Then global_config`.  The solution I provided makes the code to call `global_config` only if it is necessary...

Comment: What I mean is: I still need to write an Auto_Open() to call global_config when the file is opened, and then I put your code in each Sub just to prevent the bug happen and break the config codes

Comment: @codingsnake99 You may put the `Sub` call in `Auto_Open()` event, **or not**. If you put the above recommended code **in all your Subs**, it will cal the Sub once, **when the Public variables do not have values** and **if something wrong happened and they lost their value**.

Comment: ok understood. Although the code is more efficient in such way, the same code still needs to be placed in each Sub. What I really want to ask in my original question is that whether it is possible to just write the code once and run it once in VBA (Like Class in Python, you can run the config class once on top of each script). That's the reason I choose answer 1 but saying that integrated your part.